# Is there a weighted.median() function?

Tags: r

I'm looking for something similar in form to `weighted.mean()`. I've found some solutions via search that write out the entire function but would appreciate something a bit more user friendly.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following packages all have a function to calculate a weighted median: 'aroma.light', 'isotone', 'limma', 'cwhmisc', 'ergm', 'laeken', 'matrixStats, 'PSCBS', and 'bigvis' (on github).

To find them I used the invaluable findFn() in the 'sos' package which is an extension for R's inbuilt help.

```
findFn('weighted median')
```

Or,

`???'weighted median'`

as ??? is a shortcut in the same way `?some.function` is for `help(some.function)`

Comment: I didn't know about findFn!  That's awesome!

Comment: Agreed on the findFn.  Very useful.  And rather than install a new package I just got some sleep.  I'm just trying to calculate the median of weighted data and did this: median(rep(x, each=w)).

Comment: Yep, median(rep(x, each=w)), would work too. But only if all your weights are integers.

Comment: Hmisc also has wtd.quantile  :)

Comment: That's going to be `median(rep(x,times=w))` if you want to give a vector with weights. The argument `each` only takes a single value. --- edit: Just saw the answer of @Jaitropmange. As (s)he said.

Answer (score 35):

Some experience using the answers from @wkmor1 and @Jaitropmange.

---

I've checked 3 functions from 3 packages, `isotone`, `laeken`, and `matrixStats`. Only `matrixStats` works properly. Other two (just as the `median(rep(x, times=w)` solution) give integer output. As long as I calculated median age of populations, decimal places matter.

#### Reproducible example. Calculation of the median age of a population

```
df <- data.frame(age = 0:100,
                 pop = spline(c(4,7,9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1),n = 101)$y)

library(isotone)
library(laeken)
library(matrixStats)

isotone::weighted.median(df$age,df$pop)
# [1] 36
laeken::weightedMedian(df$age,df$pop)
# [1] 36
matrixStats::weightedMedian(df$age,df$pop)
# [1] 36.164
median(rep(df$age, times=df$pop))
# [1] 35
```

#### Summary

`matrixStats::weightedMedian()` is the reliable solution

Comment: Note that the rep(x, times=w) method requires integer weights, so it does not apply for your case. You could approximate using: median(rep(df$age, times=1000*df$pop)), which gives 36. Whether you want a decimal output depends on your definition of median.

Comment: with one little detail... Answer 36 is correct according to definition of [weighted median on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median).

Comment: yeah... we have no better reference than wikipedia

Comment: I do not understand the sarcasm here. Is it not quite devastating to have many functions for the same thing, but with different results?
How do you know that `matrixStats::weightedMedian()` gives the _reliable solution_? [The code](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/blob/master/src/weightedMedian_lowlevel_template.h) seems to suggest it should produce the [weighted percentile method result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Weighted_percentile), but the values are different from `spatstat::weighted.median()` which uses this method and yields `35.66291` to the problem above.

Comment: Of course, instead of choosing one way to compute the weighted median, we can also use the weighted median over all of them...

Answer (score 29):

To calculate the weighted median of a vector `x` using a same length vector of (integer) weights `w`:

```
median(rep(x, times=w))
```

Comment: This only works with integer weights. Weights in survey data are typically decimals.

Comment: Very bad idea. What happens if `w` has very large values? Filling memory just to compute a median is unwise.

Answer (score 9):

This is just a simple solution, ready to use almost anywhere.

```
weighted.median <- function(x, w) {
  w <- w[order(x)]
  x <- x[order(x)]

  prob <- cumsum(w)/sum(w)
  ps <- which(abs(prob - .5) == min(abs(prob - .5)))
  return(x[ps])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Really old post but I just came across it and did some testing of the different methods. `spatstat::weighted.median()` seemed to be about 14 times faster than `median(rep(x, times=w))` and its actually noticeable if you want to run the function more than a couple times. Testing was with a relatively large survey, about 15,000 people.

Comment: This function is now in the `{spatstat.geom}` package : `spatstat.geom::weighted.median()`

Answer (score 4):

One can also use `stats::density` to create a weighted PDF, then convert this to a CDF, as elaborated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373269/why-does-this-simple-weighted-quantile-differ-from-hmiscwtd-quantile-which-me):

```
my_wtd_q = function(x, w, prob, n = 4096) 
  with(density(x, weights = w/sum(w), n = n), 
       x[which.max(cumsum(y*(x[2L] - x[1L])) >= prob)])
```

Then `my_wtd_q(x, w, .5)` will be the weighted median.

One could also be more careful to ensure that the total area under the `density` is one by re-normalizing.

Answer (score 4):

A way in *base* to get a *weighted median* will be to order by the values and build the `cumsum` of the weights and get the value(s) at `sum * 0.5` of the weights.

```
medianWeighted <- function(x, w, q=.5) {
  n <- length(x)
  i <- order(x)
  w <- cumsum(w[i])
  p <- w[n] * q
  j <- findInterval(p, w)
  Vectorize(function(p,j) if(w[n] <= 0) NA else
    if(j < 1) x[i[1]] else
      if(j == n) x[i[n]] else
        if(w[j] == p) (x[i[j]] + x[i[j+1]]) / 2 else
          x[i[j+1]])(p,j)
}
```

What will have the following results with simple input data.

```
medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(1, 2))
#[1] 40
median(rep(c(10, 40), c(1, 2)))
#[1] 40

medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(2, 1))
#[1] 10
median(rep(c(10, 40), c(2, 1)))
#[1] 10

medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(1.5, 2))
#[1] 40
medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(3, 4))
#[1] 40
median(rep(c(10, 40), c(3, 4)))
#[1] 40

medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(1.5, 1.5))
#[1] 25
medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(3, 3))
#[1] 25
median(rep(c(10, 40), c(3, 3)))
#[1] 25

medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(0, 1))
#[1] 40
medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(1, 0))
#[1] 10
medianWeighted(c(10, 40), c(0, 0))
#[1] NA
```

It can also be used for other qantiles

```
medianWeighted(1:10, 10:1, seq(0, 1, 0.25))
[1]  1  2  4  6 10
```

Compare with other methods.

```
#Functions from other Answers
weighted.median <- function(x, w) {
  w <- w[order(x)]
  x <- x[order(x)]

  prob <- cumsum(w)/sum(w)
  ps <- which(abs(prob - .5) == min(abs(prob - .5)))
  return(x[ps])
}

my_wtd_q = function(x, w, prob, n = 4096) 
  with(density(x, weights = w/sum(w), n = n), 
       x[which.max(cumsum(y*(x[2L] - x[1L])) >= prob)])

weighted.quantile <- function(x, w, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                              na.rm = FALSE, names = TRUE) {

  if (any(probs > 1) | any(probs < 0)) stop("'probs' outside [0,1]")

  if (length(w) == 1) w <- rep(w, length(x))
  if (length(w) != length(x)) stop("w must have length 1 or be as long as x")

  if (isTRUE(na.rm)) {
    w <- x[!is.na(x)]
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  }

  w <- w[order(x)] / sum(w)
  x <- x[order(x)]

  cum_w <- cumsum(w) - w * (1 - (seq_along(w) - 1) / (length(w) - 1))
  res <- approx(x = cum_w, y = x, xout = probs)$y

  if (isTRUE(names)) {
    res <- setNames(res, paste0(format(100 * probs, digits = 7), "%"))
  }
  res
}
```

Methods

```
M <- alist(
  medRep = median(rep(DF$x, DF$w)),
 isotone = isotone::weighted.median(DF$x, DF$w),
 laeken = laeken::weightedMedian(DF$x, DF$w),
 spatstat1 = spatstat.geom::weighted.median(DF$x, DF$w, type=1),
 spatstat2 = spatstat.geom::weighted.median(DF$x, DF$w, type=2),
 spatstat4 = spatstat.geom::weighted.median(DF$x, DF$w, type=4),
 survey = survey::svyquantile(~x, survey::svydesign(id=~1, weights=~w, data=DF), 0.5)$x[1],
 RAndres = weighted.median(DF$x, DF$w),
 matrixStats = matrixStats::weightedMedian(DF$x, DF$w),
 MichaelChirico = my_wtd_q(DF$x, DF$w, .5),
 Leonardo = weighted.quantile(DF$x, DF$w, .5),
 GKi = medianWeighted(DF$x, DF$w)
)
```

Results

```
DF <- data.frame(x=c(10, 40), w=c(1, 2))
sapply(M, eval)
#        medRep        isotone         laeken      spatstat1      spatstat2 
#      40.00000       40.00000       40.00000       40.00000       25.00000 
#     spatstat4         survey        RAndres    matrixStats MichaelChirico 
#      17.50000       40.00000       10.00000       30.00000       34.15005 
#  Leonardo.50%            GKi 
#      25.00000       40.00000 

DF <- data.frame(x=c(10, 40), w=c(1, 1))
sapply(M, eval)
#        medRep        isotone         laeken      spatstat1      spatstat2 
#      25.00000       25.00000       40.00000       10.00000       10.00000 
#     spatstat4         survey        RAndres    matrixStats MichaelChirico 
#      10.00000       10.00000       10.00000       25.00000       25.05044 
#  Leonardo.50%            GKi 
#      25.00000       25.00000
```

In those two cases only *isotone* and *GKi* give identical results compared to what `median(rep(x, w))` returns.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with the `survey` package, assuming you've defined your survey design and `x` is your variable of interest:

```
svyquantile(~x, mydesign, c(0.5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I got here looking for weighted quantiles, so I thought I might as well leave for future readers what I ended up with. Naturally, using probs = 0.5 will return the weighted median.

I started with MichaelChirico's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942470/4825192), which unfortunately was off at the edges. Then I decided to switch from `density()` to `approx()`. Finally, I believe I nailed the correction factor to ensure consistency with the default algorithm of the unweighted `quantile()`.

```r
weighted.quantile <- function(x, w, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                              na.rm = FALSE, names = TRUE) {

  if (any(probs > 1) | any(probs < 0)) stop("'probs' outside [0,1]")

  if (length(w) == 1) w <- rep(w, length(x))
  if (length(w) != length(x)) stop("w must have length 1 or be as long as x")

  if (isTRUE(na.rm)) {
    w <- w[!is.na(w)]
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  }

  w <- w[order(x)] / sum(w)
  x <- x[order(x)]

  cum_w <- cumsum(w) - w * (1 - (seq_along(w) - 1) / (length(w) - 1))
  res <- approx(x = cum_w, y = x, xout = probs)$y

  if (isTRUE(names)) {
    res <- setNames(res, paste0(format(100 * probs, digits = 7), "%"))
  }
  res
}
```

When weights are uniform, the weighted quantiles are identical to regular unweighted quantiles:

```r
x <- rnorm(100)
stopifnot(stopifnot(identical(weighted.quantile(x, w = 1), quantile(x)))
```

Example using the same data as in the `weighted.mean()` man page.

```
x <- c(3.7, 3.3, 3.5, 2.8)
w <- c(5,   5,   4,   1)/15
stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(
  weighted.quantile(x, w, 0:4/4, names = FALSE),
  c(2.8, 3.33611111111111, 3.46111111111111, 3.58157894736842,
    3.7)
)))
```

And this is for whoever solely wants the weighted median value:

```r
weighted.median <- function(x, w, ...) {
  weighted.quantile(x, w, probs = 0.5, names = FALSE, ...)
}
```

Comment: Note there's a  bug in this code:
`w <- x[!is.na(x)]`  in the `na.rm` if block is a typo and should be `w <- w[!is.na(w)]`