# pivot table with weighted medians

Tags: r, postgresql, pivot-table, median

This task seems very simple and yet I still can't find an answer. I've seen solutions for weighted averages (i.e. means) in pivot tables but not weighted medians.

I need to create a pivot table with weighted medians (using two columns, one with the value and one with the weight–the quantity of each value to be calculated towards the median). In other words…

```
city           value    weight
Phoenix        100      40
Phoenix        140      12
Phoenix        500      15
San Francisco  700      5
San Francisco  300      5
San Francisco  350      1
San Francisco  600      1
```

will return…

```
city           weighted median
Phoenix        100
San Francisco  475
```

I've been trying to find an adequate solution in PostgreSQL and R but so far no luck. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can try this:

```
require("plyr")

> ddply(df, ~city, summarise, median=median(rep(value, weight)))
           city median
1       Phoenix    100
2 San Francisco    475
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(city=c("Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Phoenix",
                        "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco"),
                 value=c(100, 140, 500, 700, 300, 350, 600),
                 weight=c(40, 12, 15, 5, 5, 1, 1))
```

Have a look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748725/is-there-a-weighted-median-function-for-r) for more information on calculating weighted medians in R.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This seems like it should work yet I keep getting an `Error: invalid 'times' argument` message. Not familiar with this package. Both the value and weight are integers.

Comment: I updated, please try again.

Comment: same error message–it does work with the data frame you've created of course, so is it possible null values are throwing it off?

Comment: I believe your data set has some problem, but I don't know what it is.  If it really looked like the sample in your OP, there should be no error.

Comment: Just need to remove null values. Thanks Tim!