# How to create subrows in R summary table with survey weighting

Tags: r, datatable, row, cluster-analysis

I want to create a summary statistics table which reports the mean/median for each variable by region, and in the rows compare the statistic between US born and immigrants in the sample, as well as overall. I don't know the code that can allow me to group the table in multiple ways.

Here is the code I have come up with so far:

```
#the data frame 
structure(list(AGE = c(40L, 23L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 33L, 32L, 63L, 
22L, 24L), FAMSIZE = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), HYPERTEN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ALC = c(0, 2, 
3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2), region_group = c("Region 4", "Region 3", 
"Region 4", "Region 3", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 1", "Region 2", 
"Region 4", "Region 4"), PSU = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), IMMIGRANT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), SAMPWEIGHT_MERGE = c(65, 860.4, 
94.4, 9146, 170.8, 310.4, 755.2, 1053.4, 3964.4, 706.2), STRATA = c(6296L, 
6165L, 6296L, 6224L, 6045L, 6083L, 6029L, 6073L, 6287L, 6247L
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame") 
 
#weighting data frame so accounts for sample design
sample_survey<- as_survey_design(A, ids=PSU, weights=SAMPWEIGHT_MERGE, strata=STRATA, nest=TRUE) 
options(survey.lonely.psu="remove")

#producing desired table 
out1<-sample_survey %>% 
  group_by(region_group) %>% 
  summarise("Number of drinks (mean)"=survey_mean(ALC),
            "Number of drinks (median)"=survey_median(ALC),"Hypertension"=survey_mean(HYPERTEN), "Family Size"=survey_mean(FAMSIZE), "Age"=survey_median(AGE))

out1=t(out1) 
out1

#But here is what I hope the table can look like, such that the mean/median amongst all individuals, immigrant=0 and the immigrant=1 group are all displayed for each variable 

                           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
region_group                 "Region 1"   "Region 2"   "Region 3"   "Region 4"  
Number of drinks (all)      "1.663778"   "2.131566"   "1.744107"   "2.009594"  
   IMMIGRANT==0                 
   IMMIGRANT==1  
Number of drinks (mean)_se   "0.1375124"  "0.1245772"  "0.0957500"  "0.1199982" 
Number of drinks (all)         "1"          "2"          "1"          "2"
   IMMIGRANT==0                 
   IMMIGRANT==1           
Number of drinks (median)_se "0.0000000"  "0.2531528"  "0.0000000"  "0.2533324" 
Hypertension  (all)           "0.1340147"  "0.1685102"  "0.1834528"  "0.1225418" 
   IMMIGRANT==0                 
   IMMIGRANT==1 
Hypertension_se              "0.01623974" "0.01529678" "0.01463019" "0.01475651"
Family \n    (all)        Size    "3.121062"   "2.883905"   "3.107202"   "3.265012"  
   IMMIGRANT==0                 
   IMMIGRANT==1 
Family \n            Size_se "0.11668906" "0.07435704" "0.08004129" "0.11138869"
Age      (all)                    "30"         "27"         "30"         "28"        
   IMMIGRANT==0                 
   IMMIGRANT==1 
Age_se                       "1.3615690"  "1.0126110"  "0.7616152"  "0.7599972"
```

Thank you!

Comment: @akrun oops sorry! Thank you for pointing that out, somehow a comma got left out. Should be running properly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`tables` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) :

```
library(tables)
tables::tabular((ALC+HYPERTEN)*(IMMIGRANT=factor(IMMIGRANT)+1)*(weighted.mean+median)*Arguments(w = SAMPWEIGHT_MERGE)~(region=factor(region_group)), data=data)

                                 region                    
          IMMIGRANT               Region 1 Region 2 Region 3
 ALC      0         weighted.mean 2.816    0.0000   0.172   
                    median        2.500    0.0000   1.000   
          1         weighted.mean   NaN    0.0000     NaN   
                    median           NA    0.0000      NA   
          All       weighted.mean 2.816    0.0000   0.172   
                    median        2.500    0.0000   1.000   
 HYPERTEN 0         weighted.mean 0.000    1.0000   0.000   
                    median        0.000    1.0000   0.000   
          1         weighted.mean   NaN    0.0000     NaN   
                    median           NA    0.0000      NA   
          All       weighted.mean 0.000    0.7724   0.000   
                    median        0.000    0.5000   0.000
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the idea. Although I am wondering does this mean/median account for the survey weighting? And how would the code look to create a table multiple variables (i.e. hypertension, age)?

Comment: I added HYPERTEN as example for a new variable. Looking how to take into account weighting

Comment: Ok thank you so much! Although it's a little tricky because hypertension is a binary variable (either individuals have it or do not), so I don't need/want to calculate the median of that variable.

Comment: See my edit, you can pass `Arguments(w = SAMPWEIGHT_MERGE)` to `weighted.mean`

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Thanks for looking into that. Is there a way to calculate the weighted median too?

Comment: weighted.median isn't in base R, but there are many implementations of it :https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748879/13513328