# Deriving median from grouped frequencies in R

Tags: r, median

I have the following example table where I am required to find the median age of a herd of animals. Not only does it have a `0`, it is also has a grouped frequency of animals for a given age.

```
library(tidyverse)
a<-data.frame(Age=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              Individuals=c(3655,2535,898,235,559,265,258,3659,7895,3655))
a%>%summarise(Age=as.numeric(Age),
          Median=sort(as.numeric(Age)*Persons/sum(Individuals)))
```

I understand that the standard `median()` option does not work. I tried to be clever and attempted something like: `median(rep(a$Age, a$Individuals))`, but the memory consumption was too much. Besides, I think it will fail with a larger dataset.

Comment: There is a `weighted.median` function in [spatstat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/), [among others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748725/is-there-a-weighted-median-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be abit clever and do:

```
a %>%
  arrange(Age) %>%
  summarise(median = Age[findInterval(sum(Individuals)/2, cumsum(Individuals)) + 1])

  median
1      7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `uncount` the original data frame and then use the standard `median` function.

```
a %>% uncount(Individuals) %>% summarise(Median=median(Age))
  Median
1      7
```

And to check:

```
> sum(a$Individuals)/2
[1] 11807
> sum(a$Individuals[1:7])
[1] 8405
> sum(a$Individuals[1:8])
[1] 12064
```

All good.

Comment: OP just stated that the memory consumption for this is too much. Also wont work for large counts

Comment: In which case, my rough and ready check provides a memory minimal custom method for obtaining the median.

Comment: i do not think your check provide the median. You just used the value obtained from uncount to try and do a quick check.