# Median of grouped data

Tags: r, statistics, median

I have a dataset containing the number of infants born per gestational week.

I am trying to determine the median gestational age of delivery based on the frequency of infants born for this particular year

For example:

| GA | num_infants_born |
| --- | --- |
| 20 weeks | 16 |
| 21 weeks | 22 |
| 22 weeks | 34 |
| 23 weeks | 45 |
| 24 weeks | 60 |
| 25 weeks | 67 |
| 26 weeks | 94 |

and onwards, until 41 weeks. The distribution is (not surprisingly) left skewed

I also calculated cumulative frequencies using

```
data$cumulative_freq = cumsum(data$num_infants_born)
```

Do I use the cumulative_freq column to calculate the median number of infants born that corresponds to a gestational week? Using

```
median(medianGA2001a$cumulative_freq)
```

gives me an unexpected number.

I am expecting the median GA to be around 35 weeks, based on the distribution

Comment: Unfortunately `median` return an average of two central values if they are even, so you wil end with i.e. week34/35 .But `with(medianGA2001a, GA[which(num_infants_born==quantile(num_infants_born, 0.5))])` should give you a unique median week in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a weighted median. You first want the weeks as numeric, which you get using `gsub` if not yet available

```
dat$GA_num <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', dat$GA))
```

Then, use `weightedMedian` from the `matrixStats` package with the number of infants as weights.

```
matrixStats::weightedMedian(dat$GA_num, w=dat$num_infants_born)
# [1] 24.34646
```

**Note,** that there are several definitions of the weighted mean. For a comprehensive discussion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2748725/6574038).

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(GA = c("20 weeks", "21 weeks", "22 weeks", "23 weeks", 
"24 weeks", "25 weeks", "26 weeks"), num_infants_born = c(16L, 
22L, 34L, 45L, 60L, 67L, 94L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you're going to want to do something like this:

```r
# Your gestational data:
gestational_data <- data.frame(GA_weeks = c(20:26),
                               num_infants_born = c(16,22,34,45,60,67,94))

# See the apply() documentation by running 
# ?apply

apply(gestational_data,
      1,
      function(x){
        rep(x[1],x[2])
      }) |>
  unlist()|>
  median()
```