# How do I calculate weighted median instead of weighted mean for single-arm meta-analysis?

Tags: r, median, weighted

I am trying to calculate weighted median instead of weighted mean for meta-analysis.
I used to use `metamean` but unfortunately no `metamedian` if the data was skewed.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748725/is-there-a-weighted-median-function) but it is irrelevant in case of meta-analysis.

Here is my prior code.

```
library(meta)
data(Fleiss1993cont)
# Meta-analysis of weighted mean from each study in a single arm meta-analysis
m1 <- metamean(n.psyc, mean.psyc, sd.psyc,   data = Fleiss1993cont, studlab = study); forest(m1)
```

Comment: Try the metamedian package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metamedian/index.html